# "My order" table just with orders from current store view

Tags: magento

I have one maganto installation (1.4.0.1) with several web site and several store/store view. Also I have different product in all store views. When I go My Account-> My orders in the table is show the orders from all stores. Can I config somewhere or change something in code to have list with order just from current open store view?

With other word, if I go on store 2 on my web site mywebsite.com/store2 in my orders mywebsite.com/store2/sales/order/history/ it show orders history from all web sites, but I need me to show orders just form "store2".

I hope someone have answer for this or similar issue and I will be grateful if help me.

Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    /*GetCurrent Website Name*/
    $currentWebsiteName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getName();        
    $currentWebsiteName_LIKE_PHRASE = '%'.$currentWebsiteName.'%';

    /*Filter the Order Collection by Current Website Name*/
    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('store_name', array('like' => $currentWebsiteName_LIKE_PHRASE))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

   /*Note the Below Line*/
   ->addAttributeToFilter('store_name', array('like' => $currentWebsiteName_LIKE_PHRASE))
```

Am filtering by current website name. Just got the **sales_flat_order** table can view this column '**store_name**' where you can find it **also contains the website Name**.

Unfortunately i can't find **website id in this main order table or in its related table** to make a **JOIN statement to the order collection**. I think **you might have some order table with **_website** suffix**, if thats the case you can easily join that to our existing collection

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple.

Override the respective Sales order history block app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\History.php file into your local code pool

and just filter your collection by current store Id.

```
             $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
             $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$store_id)
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ;
```

Note these lines in the code above

```
        /*Current Store View ID*/
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        /*Filtering the order collection by current store id*/
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$store_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work nice, but now I need to change to list order by web site not by web store, I tried with $website_id= Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(); and addFieldToFilter('website_id',$website_id) but dosen't work, some suggestions

Comment: @JovanovJordan Obviously the order collection can't be ordered by website_id because it doesn't have it. Moreover we have already filtered the collection by store_id , the collection holds only the orders of that store view.

Comment: Hi Again, but I want to removed the selection form store_id and select by web sites. some suggestion on another way

Comment: @JovanovJordan just added an another answer for your latest query