# magento - How override sales order history block class (Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History)

Tags: php, magento, module, overriding, block

I followed this post to filter the order collection from customer account.
["My order" table just with orders from current store view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219629/my-order-table-just-with-orders-from-current-store-view/15220416#15220416)

But now i am trying to override the block (app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\History.php) but without success. He doesn't do the filter that i applied

I created the following files:

/app/code/local/Emm/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <global>
           <blocks>
              <sales>
                      <rewrite>
                          <history>Emm_Sales_Block_Order_History</history>
                      </rewrite>        
              </sales>
           </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

/app/etc/modules/Emm_Sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Emm_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Emm_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Emm/Sales/Block/Order/History.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Sales/Block/Order/History.php';

class Emm_Sales_Block_Order_History extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History
{
```

I'm forgetting something?
In the magento backoffice (System > Advanced ) I can see my module as enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are issue in `config.xml path`

it Should be

```
app/code/local/Emm/Sales/etc/config.xml
```

from `app/code/local/Emm/etc/config.xml`

Also Need to modify config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Emm_Sales>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Emm_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
     <blocks>
            <emmsales>
            <class>Emm_Sales_Block</class>
            </emmsales>
            <sales>
            <rewrite>
                          <order_history>Emm_Sales_Block_Order_History</order_history>
            </rewrite>        
        </sales>
    </blocks>
</config>
```

Try this

Comment: I Amit, i change the config file e moved the folder 'etc' to 'Sales' but nothing happens.

Comment: delete all file from yourmagentodir/var/cache

Comment: how to override the same in magento2? here is the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246603/override-sales-order-history-issue-in-magento2

Answer (score 1):

The error is in /app/etc/modules/Emm_Sales.xml file. XML tags are case sensitive, so you need to write codePool with capital letter, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Emm_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Emm_Sales>
    </modules> 
</config>
```

In your file, you wrote codepool instead of codePool. That was the error.

And you should also need to add order_history tag instead of just history:

```
<config>
    <global>
       <blocks>
          <sales>
                  <rewrite>
                      <order_history>Emm_Sales_Block_Order_History</order_history>
                  </rewrite>        
          </sales>
       </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your /app/code/local/Emm/etc/config.xml file.

Change the tag history by order_history

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
       <blocks>
          <sales>
                  <rewrite>
                      <order_history>Emm_Sales_Block_Order_History</order_history>
                  </rewrite>        
          </sales>
       </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```